# I want to show a clang-tidy parsing report in SonarQube, but there is no output after loading

Tags: c, build, sonarqube, llvm, clang-tidy

I want to show a clang-tidy parsing report in SonarQube (Community  Edition) using the "C ++ (Community)" plugin. But there is no output after loading. From sonarcub I need to display clang-tidy reports and no analysis is needed.

file sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=myProject
sonar.cxx.clangtidy.reportPath=clang-tidy-report
sonar.cxx.errorRecoveryEnabled=True
sonar.verbose=true 
sonar.cxx.jsonCompilationDatabase=compile_commands.json
#----- Default SonarQube server
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/
```

I used in bash:

The build wrapper:

```
    build-wrapper --out-dir bw-outputs ./build.sh
```

And using the SonarQube Scanner:

```
    sonar-scanner
```

I found this site that shows how to work with analyzers:
https://www.spazioit.com/SAFeToolsetHelp/Step4-ConfigureSonarQubeAnalyses.html

Console output:

```
   12:26:26.972 INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 112ms
   12:26:26.981 DEBUG: Report metadata written to 
   /home/bivk/bivk_merge/bivk_bootloader/.scannerwork/report-task.txt
   12:26:26.981 INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=bootloder
   12:26:26.981 INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has 
   processed the submitted analysis report
   12:26:26.981 INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task? 
   id=AXkiurWiHwwwwqfrQgb
   12:26:26.992 DEBUG: Post-jobs : Final report
   12:26:26.992 INFO: Executing post-job 'Final report'
   12:26:26.992 WARN: Preprocessor: 4 include directive error(s). This is only relevant if parser 
   creates 
   syntax errors. The preprocessor searches for include files in the with 
  'sonar.cxx.includeDirectories' 
   defined directories and order.
   12:26:26.992 WARN: Source code parser: 2 syntax error(s) detected. Syntax errors could cause 
   invalid 
   software metric values. Root cause are typically missing includes, missing macros or compiler 
   specific 
   extensions.
   12:26:26.998 INFO: Analysis total time: 35.382 s
   12:26:27.002 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   12:26:27.003 INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
```

Comment: It says your code didn't compile.

Comment: I compile this code GCC, i have't problem

Comment: OK, but: `12:26:26.992 WARN: Source code parser: 2 syntax error(s) detected.`  Which I interpret as "it didn't compile."  Not sure why that's a warning; if it doesn't compile, it won't run either.

Comment: I assume this is a static code analyzer?

Comment: Note that the syntax error is the final thing that it reports; it appears to make no further analysis.

Comment: Also i compile and analyse this code https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/tree/master/sonarqube-scanner-build-wrapper-linux - it also visualisetion doesn't work

Comment: Does it report a similar syntax error?

Comment: `Does it report a similar syntax error?` yes